# Finding all the common substrings of given two strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have come across a problem statement to find the **all the common sub-strings between the given two sub-strings**  such a way that in every case you have to print the longest sub-string. The problem statement is as follows:

> Write a program to find the common substrings between the two given strings.  However, do not include substrings that are contained within longer common substrings.
>
> For example, given the input strings `eatsleepnightxyz` and `eatsleepabcxyz`, the results should be:
>
> - `eatsleep` (due to `eatsleepnightxyz` `eatsleepabcxyz`)
> - `xyz` (due to `eatsleepnightxyz` `eatsleepabcxyz`)
> - `a` (due to `eatsleepnightxyz` `eatsleepabcxyz`)
> - `t` (due to `eatsleepnightxyz` `eatsleepabcxyz`)
>
> However, the result set should *not* include `e` from
>   `eatsleepnightxyz` `eatsleepabcxyz`, because both `e`s are already contained in the `eatsleep` mentioned above.  Nor should you include `ea`, `eat`, `ats`, etc., as those are also all covered by `eatsleep`.
>
> In this, you don't have to make use of String utility methods like: contains, indexOf, StringTokenizer, split and replace.

My Algorithm is as follows: I am starting with brute force and will switch to more optimized solution when I improve my basic understanding.

```
 For String S1:
     Find all the substrings of S1 of all the lengths
     While doing so: Check if it is also a substring of 
     S2.
```

Attempt to figure out the time complexity of my approach.

**Let the two given strings be n1-String and n2-String**

1. The number of substrings of S1 is clearly n1(n1+1)/2.
2. But we have got to find the average length a substring of S1.
3. Let’s say it is m. We’ll find m separately.
4. Time Complexity to check whether an m-String is a substring of an
   n-String is O(n*m).
5. Now, we are checking for each m-String is a substring of S2,
   which is an n2-String.
6. This, as we have seen above, is an O(n<sup>2</sup> m) algorithm.
7. The time required by the overall algorithm then is
8. Tn=(Number of substrings in S1) * (average substring lengthtime for character comparison procedure)
9. By performing certain calculations, I came to conclusion that the
   time complexity is O(n<sup>3</sup> m<sup>2</sup>)
10. Now, our job is to find m in terms of n1.

**Attempt to find m in terms of n1.**

T<sub>n</sub> = (n)(1) + (n-1)(2) + (n-2)(3) + ..... + (2)(n-1) + (1)(n)
where T<sub>n</sub> is the sum of lengths of all the substrings.

Average will be the division of this sum by the total number of Substrings produced.

This, simply is a summation and division problem whose solution is as follows O(n)

**Therefore...**

Running time of my algorithm is O(n^5).

With this in mind I wrote the following code:

```
 package pack.common.substrings;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Set;

 public class FindCommon2 {
    public static final Set<String> commonSubstrings = new      LinkedHashSet<String>();

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    printCommonSubstrings("neerajisgreat", "neerajisnotgreat");
    System.out.println(commonSubstrings);
}

 public static void printCommonSubstrings(String s1, String s2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length();) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j = i; j < s1.length(); j++) {
            String subStr = s1.substring(i, j + 1);
            if (isSubstring(subStr, s2)) {
                list.add(subStr);
            }
        }
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            String s = list.get(list.size() - 1);
            commonSubstrings.add(s);
            i += s.length();
        }
    }
 }

 public static boolean isSubstring(String s1, String s2) {
    boolean isSubstring = true;
    int strLen = s2.length();
    int strToCheckLen = s1.length();
    if (strToCheckLen > strLen) {
        isSubstring = false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= (strLen - strToCheckLen); i++) {
            int index = i;
            int startingIndex = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < strToCheckLen; j++) {
                if (!(s1.charAt(j) == s2.charAt(index))) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    index++;
                }
            }
            if ((index - startingIndex) < strToCheckLen) {
                isSubstring = false;
            } else {
                isSubstring = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isSubstring;
 }
}
```

Explanation for my code:

```
 printCommonSubstrings: Finds all the substrings of S1 and 
                        checks if it is also a substring of 
                        S2.
 isSubstring : As the name suggests, it checks if the given string 
               is a substring of the other string.
```

Issue: Given the inputs

```
  S1 = “neerajisgreat”;
  S2 = “neerajisnotgreat”
  S3 = “rajeatneerajisnotgreat”
```

In case of S1 and S2, the output should be: `neerajis` and `great`
but in case of S1 and S3, the output should have been: 
`neerajis`, `raj`, `great`, `eat` but still I am getting `neerajis` and `great` as output. I need to figure this out.

How should I design my code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You would be better off with a proper algorithm for the task rather than a brute-force approach.  Wikipedia describes two common solutions to the [longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem): [suffix-tree](/questions/tagged/suffix-tree) and [dynamic-programming](/questions/tagged/dynamic-programming).

The dynamic programming solution takes O(*n m*) time and O(*n m*) space.  This is pretty much a straightforward Java translation of the Wikipedia pseudocode for the longest common substring:

```
public static Set<String> longestCommonSubstrings(String s, String t) {
    int[][] table = new int[s.length()][t.length()];
    int longest = 0;
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < t.length(); j++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(j)) {
                continue;
            }

            table[i][j] = (i == 0 || j == 0) ? 1
                                             : 1 + table[i - 1][j - 1];
            if (table[i][j] > longest) {
                longest = table[i][j];
                result.clear();
            }
            if (table[i][j] == longest) {
                result.add(s.substring(i - longest + 1, i + 1));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, you want all of the common substrings, not just the longest.  You can enhance this algorithm to include shorter results.  Let's examine the table for the example inputs `eatsleepnightxyz` and `eatsleepabcxyz`:

```
  e a t s l e e p a b c x y z
e 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
a 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
t 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
s 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
l 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
e 1 0 0 0 0 6 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
e 1 0 0 0 0 1 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0
n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
i 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
g 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
t 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
x 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
y 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
z 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
```

- The `eatsleep` result is obvious: that's the `12345678` diagonal streak at the top-left.
- The `xyz` result is the `123` diagonal at the bottom-right.
- The `a` result is indicated by the `1` near the top (second row, ninth column).
- The `t` result is indicated by the `1` near the bottom left.

What about the other `1`s at the left, the top, and next to the `6` and `7`?  Those don't count because they appear within the rectangle formed by the `12345678` diagonal — in other words, they are already covered by `eatsleep`.

I recommend doing one pass doing nothing but building the table. Then, make a second pass, iterating backwards from the bottom-right, to gather the result set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100826/discussion-between-neeraj-dorle-and-200-success).

Answer (score 5):

Typically this type of substring matching is done with the assistance of a separate data structure called a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (pronounced try).  The specific variant that best suits this problem is a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).  Your first step should be to take your inputs and build a suffix tree.  Then you'll need to use the suffix tree to determine the longest common substring, which is a good exercise.